# Setting title and axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, axis-labels

I'm trying to set my plot title and x and y label. Totals are all numbers float64.
I'm trying to do it as simple as possible way.

Here is the part of my code:

```
plt.close('all')
cand_all =pd.DataFrame({'Bachmann':[total15],
                        'Romney':[total2],
                        'Obama':[total3],
                        'Roemer': [total4],
                       'Pawlenty':[total5],
                       'Johnson':[total6],
                       'Paul':[total7],
                       'Santorum':[total8],
                       'Cain':[total9],
                       'Gingrich':[total10],
                       'McCotter':[total12],
                       'Huntsman':[total13],
                       'Perry':[total14]}) 



cand_all.plot.bar()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide a axes (`ax`) parameter.

```
ax=plt.subplot(111)
cand_all.plot.bar(ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('xlabel')
ax.set_ylabel('ylabel')
ax.set_title('title')
```

Note that for `pandas` dataframes, name of the index (if exists) would be automatically become x label.